# four consecutive numbers including zero

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-functions

I would like to prove the obvious: We have four consecutive numbers,some of them are negative and some of them are positive.Then the product is equal to: zero(equivalent to the set of these four consecutive numbers contains zero)
I've thought of using the Bolzano theorem on f(x)=x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3) but it didn't work.

Comment: You could do it by cases, with the extremal cases being $-3,-3,2,0$ and $0,1,2,3$.

Comment: What is the definition of "consecutive numbers"?

Comment: @henry integers that the distance between them is one.(a quick and drafty definition)

Comment: Then there are eight possibilities $(2,1,0,-1)$, $(1,0,-1,0)$, $(1,0,-1,-2)$, $(0,1,0,-1)$, $(0,-1,0,1)$, $(-1,0,1,2)$, $(-1,0,1,0)$, and $(-2,-1,0,1)$, and they all have products of $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline:  1)$n < 0;$ 2) $n+3 > 0; $ 3) one of the remaining terms ($n+1$ or $n+2$) must be 0; therefore 4) product must be zero.

1) 2) and 3) will be proven below in *excruciating* detail.

=======

Four consecutive numbers:  $n, n+1, n+2, n+3$.  Or generally $n + i; 0\le i \le 3$.

Some are negative:  $n + i < 0$ for some $i$.  So $n < -i$.  As $i \ge 0$, $n < -i < 0$.

Some are positive: $n + i > 0$ for some $i$.  $n > -i$.  As $i \le 3$ $n > -3$.

So $-3 < n < 0$ and $0 < n+3 < 3$.

Let $k = \min(|n|, n+3)$.  Then $k \in \mathbb N$ and $0< k < 3$. So $n +k \in \{n,n+1, n+2, n+3\}=\{n+3-3, n+3-2, n+3-1, n+3-0\}$.  So $n+3 - k\in \{n,n+1,n+2,n+3\}$.

If $k = |n|$ then $n+k = n-n = 0$ and $\prod(n+i) = 0$.

If $k = n+3$ then $n+3 - k = (n+3)-(n+3) = 0$ and $\prod(n+i) = 0$.

===

Answer (score 1):

If you have four consecutive integers and they include both negative and positive integers,then $0$ must come in between and anything $\times0=0.$

Just because you wanted a more 'mathematical' proof:-

If $n<0$ and $n+k>0$ are any two of the numbers we have, then we can say $n,n+1,...n+k,...n,n+1,...n+k,...$ all belong the numbers we have. Let $n+k=a$. Can you see that $n+(k−a)$ is also one of the numbers?

However, I feel we are using the same logic.

Comment: This is what I would like to prove actually.I mean in the general case of a(a+1)(a+2)(a+3).It might just be common sense

Comment: @Jac Ok...I will edit my answer if I manage to find a mathematical solution...

Comment: @Jac Btw,you can prove this in a brute force manner easily....Consider the following cases-(one positive,three negative);(two positive,two negative);(three positive,one negative)....

Comment: @Jac This method helps you to prove it for a finite number of cases (for eg. you mentioned 4)...but this not a generalized method...

Comment: @Jac observe that if $n<0$ and $n+k>0$, then we can say $n,n+1,...n+k,...$ all belong the numbers we have. Let $n+k=a$. Can you see that $n+(k-a)$ is also a number we have?

Comment: Yes, I am searching for a generalized method or it might be only witch-hunting..

Comment: @Jac See my last comment...

Comment: @jac yep yep workin on it

Comment: Yes it is somewhere among the n,n+1,...,n+k

Comment: @Jac So, we are done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47518/discussion-between-jac-and-tatan).